# checkbox should be checked automatically based on the updates

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have JSP page in which there are checkboxes displayed across each textbox. There are 3 colums with 2 textboxes and 1 dropdown list.

If any change is done to the textbox value or any dropdown value is changed, the corresponding checkbox should be checked automatically.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** (the image below shows the screen as mentioned):
[image: Image as per the description]

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery `change` function: http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```